# Ошибка в работе сложения bitset

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <cstdio>
 
template <size_t N>
std::bitset<N> sum (const std::bitset<N>& b1, const std::bitset<N>& b2) {
    std::bitset<N> result;
    bool carry = false;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < N ; ++i) {
        unsigned value = b1[i] + b2[i] + (carry ? 1 : 0);
        carry = value > 1;
        result[i] = value % 2;
        printf ("[%d] %u %u -> %d (%d)\n", (int)i, b1[i], b2[i], result[i], (int)carry);
    }
    return result;
}
 
int main () {
    std::bitset<10> first(20);
    std::bitset<10> second (15);
    std::cout << sum (first, second).to_ulong() << std::endl;
}
```

[image: Ошибки и вывод][image: Что должно выводить]

Неправильно работает побитовое сложение bitset. Как исправить или какие еще есть варианты сложения двоичных чисел? **1 скрин ошибки и вывод. 2 скрин что должно выводить**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> constexpr bool operator[]( std::size_t pos ) const;
> reference operator[]( std::size_t pos );
> ```
>
> ```
> printf ("[%d] %u %u -> %d (%d)\n", (int)i, b1[i], b2[i], result[i], (int)carry);
> ```

Через `%u` и `%d` выводится то, что не является (unsigned) int'ом. А именно, некий `reference`.

https://ideone.com/gNvPKh

```
printf ("[%d] %u %u -> %u (%d)\n", (int)i, (unsigned)b1[i], (unsigned)b2[i], (unsigned)result[i], (int)carry);
```

```
[0] 0 1 -> 1 (0)
[1] 0 1 -> 1 (0)
[2] 1 1 -> 0 (1)
[3] 0 1 -> 0 (1)
[4] 1 0 -> 0 (1)
[5] 0 0 -> 1 (0)
[6] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[7] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[8] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[9] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
35
```

И вообще, я бы код записал покрасивее: https://ideone.com/BX2PS9

```
template <size_t N> std::bitset<N> sum (const std::bitset<N>& b1, const std::bitset<N>& b2) {
    std::bitset<N> result;
    unsigned value = 0;
 
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        value += b1[i] + b2[i];
        result[i] = value & 1;
        value >>= 1;
 
        printf ("[%z] %u %u -> %u (%u)\n", i, (unsigned)b1[i], (unsigned)b2[i], (unsigned)result[i], value);
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

<s>Кстати, можно ещё немного поиграться с форматом и присобачить `%hhu` - это формат для числового вывода `unsigned char`, так что я [пока не знаю, разрешено ли стандартом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1244546/178988) его применять к `bool`, но они оба однобайтовые, и всё работает: https://ideone.com/kLoP8L</s>

```
printf ("[%z] %hhu %hhu -> %hhu (%u)\n", i, b1[i], b2[i], result[i], value);
```

`%hhu` не работает - выведен мусор.

PS: А ещё есть сомнительное место, но может быть так и задумано: перенос из последнего разряда. По идее результатам может быть `std::bitset<N+1>`.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Всё работает как и задумывалось

Comment: @Boost3d, добавил ещё финт с форматом.

Answer (score 2):

Шаблонный класс `std::bitset` [имеет](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at) две версии оператора `operator[]` — константную и неконстантную версии:

```
constexpr bool operator[]( std::size_t pos ) const;
reference operator[]( std::size_t pos );
```

где `reference` — это [вспомогательный классовый тип](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/reference), предназначенный для установки отдельных битов у объектов типа `std::bitset`.

В приведённом коде

```
printf ("[%d] %u %u -> %d (%d)\n", (int)i, b1[i], b2[i], result[i], (int)carry);
```

имеют место несоответствия между спецификаторами преобразования и типами фактически передаваемых в функцию `printf` аргументов, что ведёт к неопределённому поведению.

Выражения `b1[i]` и `b2[i]` возвращают значения типа `bool` (используется константная версия `operator[]`), которые перед передачей в функцию `printf` преобразуются в тип `int` (см.: [Вывод bool в printf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1244546)), однако, используются спецификаторы преобразования `%u`, которые говорят, что аргументы должны иметь тип `unsigned int`, следовательно поведение программы не определено.

Выражение `result[i]` возвращает значение классового типа `std::bitset<N>::reference` (используется неконстантная версия `operator[]`), но используемый спецификатор преобразования `%d` говорит, что аргумент должен иметь тип `int`, следовательно поведение программы не определено.

N1570, 7.21.6.1/9:

> [...] If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Так как класс `std::bitset<N>::reference` имеет оператор преобразования в тип `bool`, то проблемную строку можно переписать так:

```
std::printf("[%d] %d %d -> %d (%d)\n", (int)i, b1[i], b2[i], (bool)result[i], carry);
```

Вывод ([gcc](https://ideone.com/yiZkgx), [clang](https://ideone.com/NVR2WD)):

```
[0] 0 1 -> 1 (0)
[1] 0 1 -> 1 (0)
[2] 1 1 -> 0 (1)
[3] 0 1 -> 0 (1)
[4] 1 0 -> 0 (1)
[5] 0 0 -> 1 (0)
[6] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[7] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[8] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
[9] 0 0 -> 0 (0)
35
```