# Вывод bool в printf

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, printf, bool

Есть переменная:

```
bool x = true;
```

Хочу её загнать в `printf` в виде числа. Очевидно, что можно сделать

```
printf("%d", (int)x);
```

но кастить тип как-то лень и хочется сделать что-то такое:

```
printf("%hhu", x);
```

Это тоже работает поскольку с unsigned char и bool занимают по 1 байту, но разрешает ли стандарт такой вывод?

Comment: поясните пожалуйста зачем кастить оно выводит и без этого 0 или 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Неизвестные аргументы, передаваемые в вариативную функцию подвергаются расширению аргументов по-умолчанию (*default argument promotions*). Суть его в следующем:

- типы с плавающей точкой подвергаются расширению типов с плавающей точкой (*floating-point promotion*),
- Целочисленные типы и типы перечисления подвергаются целочисленному расширению (*integral promotions*)

[expr.call/12](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#12):

> [...] If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions, or a floating-point type that is subject to the floating-point promotion, **the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call**. These promotions are referred to as the *default argument promotions*.

При расширении типов с плавающей точкой значение типа `float` преобразуется к значению типа `double`. [conv.fpprom/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpprom#1):

> A prvalue of type `float` can be converted to a prvalue of type `double`. The value is unchanged.

Описание процесса целочисленного расширения довольно объёмно, см.: [conv.prom](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom).
Но что касается типа `bool`, то он при целочисленном расширении преобразуется к типу `int`, причём значение `false` преобразуется в `0`, а значение `true` преобразуется в `1`. [conv.prom/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.prom#6):

> A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true` becoming one.

Таким образом, значение типа `bool`, передаваемое в функцию `std::printf`, перед вызовом преобразуется в значение типа `int`. А значит его можно вывести так:

```
bool x = true;
printf("%d", x);
```

---

Разберём печать `bool` с помощью `%hhu`
Спецификатор преобразования `%hhu` говорит, что функция `printf` ожидает получить значение типа `unsigned int`, которое она перед выводом преобразует в значение типа `unsigned char`. Так как тип фактически передаваемого аргумента не соответствует спецификатору преобразования (`bool` расширяется до `int`)

```
bool x = true;
printf("%hhu", x);
```

то поведение программы не определено.

N1570, 7.21.6.1/9:

> [...] If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

---

P.S.

Стандарт языка не гарантирует, что тип `bool` занимает один байт. [expr.sizeof/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.sizeof#1):

> [*Note 1*: In particular, the values of `sizeof(bool)`, `sizeof(char16_­t)`, `sizeof(char32_­t)`, and `sizeof(wchar_­t)` are implementation-defined.65
> — *end note*]
>
> 65. `sizeof(bool)` is not required to be `1`.

Comment: Если любой тип меньше инта расширяется до инта, то зачем вообще спецификаторы `%hd` и `%hhd` - получается, их спокойно можно заменить на `%d`?

Comment: @Qwertiy, да, их можно заменить на `%d`. Не могу сказать зачем они нужны. Возможно, для симметрии с функцией `scanf` — там `%hd`, `%hhd` и `%d` не взаимозаменяемые.

Comment: Но `%lf` симметричным делать не стали.

Comment: а есть ли требование в с++ для printf преобразовывать аргументы обязательно?

Comment: @Qwertiy, не понял, что значит "симметричным делать не стали"? У функции `printf` спецификаторы `%f` и `%lf` эквивалентны. А у функции `scanf` не эквивалентны.

Comment: @KoVadim, что вы имеете ввиду? Обязательно ли аргументы подвергаются расширению при передаче в функцию?

Comment: именно это я и имею ввиду, есть ли требование для компилятора делать расширение. Если нет, тогда наличие модификаторов очевидно.

Comment: @KoVadim, да, есть, в первой цитате в ответе жирным выделено: `the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call`. Есть ещё статья на [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments#Default_conversions)

Comment: перечитал несколько раз. Хитро написано. Но думаю это ровно для того, что бы разрешить компилятору делать эти преобразования "виртуально" - то есть, если после преобразования ничего не поменяется, то смысл его делать. И в коде его в результате нет и возникают вопросы - а было ли преобразование

Comment: @wololo, в табличке `%lf` вообще не перечислен для [printf](//www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/), хотя [действительно работает](//ideone.com/CRtTKH). Впрочем, если сменить компилятор, то он кидает warning, что такого формата нет в ISO: http://codepad.org/05gUfLvX: `warning: ISO C++ does not support the '%lf' printf format`. Так что всё-таки несимметрично.

Comment: @Qwertiy, N1570, 7.21.6.1/7: "The length modifiers and their meanings are: ... `l` Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to ... or **has no effect** on a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion specifier." + в табличке на cppreference [перечислен](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

Comment: @wololo, да, вижу - с пометкой `(C++11)` - видимо, решили подогнать.